# Show mp3 files but select folder with QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt

Currently, I can select a folder using `QFileDialog`'s `getExistingDirectory` function. Even thought I managed to let the dialog show the files as well, I would like to filter them, i.e. display only folders and `*.mp3` files.

```
QString folder = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, "test", "", QFileDialog::ReadOnly);
```

Is this possible without creating a custom dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QFileDialog d(this);
d.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
d.setNameFilter("*.mp3");
if (d.exec())
  qDebug () << d.selectedFiles();
```

Comment: My main window is in fullscreen. Using `getExistingDirectory` makes the dialog appear, but with this the focus is still on the `MainWindow`.

Comment: And if you add `this` to the constructor of `QFileDialog`? (see edited post)

Answer (score 0):

I am on mobile rt now. Giving a kind of hints only....

On Windows and macOS, this static function will use the native file dialog and not a QFileDialog. However, the native Windows file dialog does not support displaying files in the directory chooser. You need to pass DontUseNativeDialog to display files using a QFileDialog. ( from qfiledialog documentation)

So set the 'QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog' option using 'setflags'

Then using file dialog's  'setfilter' set the filter for your MP3 files..

Comment: You don't need to set `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` manually, based on your requested settings, Qt itself will automatically decide to not use the native dialog.